# Need to Separate a String in R using grepl function

Tags: r, grepl

[image]

I have a column like this but I need to separate the weight digits from the chips name. Using grepl() function.

```
productWords[grepl(pattern = "![:digit:]", x= productWords)]
```

it's not working :/

Comment: Hi, Welcome to Stack Overflow. Your code is pasted as a picture, making it difficult fro people to help you. Also the error message would be helpful to know. Please consider looking at how to make a reproducible example here https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example with additional tips [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this with `stringr` package

```
x <- "Natural Chip 175g"
stringr::str_extract(x, '[0-9]{3}g')
```

If weights can have more than 3 digits, try this -

```
stringr::str_extract(x, '[0-9]+g')
```